# dynamic broadcast receiver in a service not receiving intent

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I have a dynamic broadcast receiver registered in a service and my service is doing some heavy sdcard read/write operation in a while(somecondition) loop.

When a broadcast is sent from my another Application (which is in other process) is not received by my broadcast receiver.

This same broadcast is received when it is not executing while loop.

I also tried to put end of loop with Thread.Sleep(100) just to give some time for broadcast receiver to  get executed but it is not working.

Any help regarding this will help me a lot.

-Thanks & regards,
Manju

```
Code below for registering BxRx:
this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTIVITY_NAME));

code below for sending broadcast:
Intent intnt = new Intent(ACTIVITY_NAME);
            intnt.putExtra("STOP_ALL_TESTING", true);
            Log.d(TAG,"Sending BX STOP_ALL_TESTING");
            myActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intnt);

code below for while loop:
while(somecondition){
:
:
:
Thred.sleep(100);
}


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Received intent: "+intent.getAction());
            boolean flag = intent.getBooleanExtra("STOP_ALL_TESTING", false);
            Log.d(TAG,"Flag set to: "+flag);

            if((boolean)intent.getBooleanExtra("STOP_ALL_TESTING",false)){
                Log.d(TAG,"Broadcast received to STOP_ALL_TESTING");
                Log.d(TAG,"Bx Rx, setting flag to stop testing as requested by user");
                synchronized(this){
                    bStopTesting=true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste your complete code.

It looks like your problem is that you have an endless loop in service's onStartCommand method. Both onStartCommand and onReceive are executed on the same thread and only one after another. Applications main thread is a Looper thread, which handles events in a sequential manner. Basically, if you have an endless operation in the service, you will block the whole main thread, which includes all the GUI, services and Broadcast receivers. Calling Thread.sleep() won't help, because the method does not return. To avoid this, you can use IntentService http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.htmlclass, which will handle intents on another thread.

```
public class HeavyService extends IntentService {

    public HeavyService() {
        super("HeavyService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //do your initialization
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //this will be executed on a separate thread. Put your heavy load here. This is
        //similar to onStartCommand of a normal service
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, While loop is on some condition and it is not endless, I need to stop this loop when i receive Broadcast from another application but that is not happening due to heavy file i/o operations happening inside the loop. I have all my logic inside this service and right now cannot think of moving it outside. Is there any other option to receive this Broadcast ? (May be I should have my heavy file i/o on a separate thread)

Comment: No, reason is that your broadcast receiver will not be invoked until the loop is over. And the loop can be over only after broadcast receiver gets the intent. Heavy input operations have no impact here. Use the IntentService and your problem will be solved :-)

Comment: Can i have a intent service inside existing service ? or it is better to have it as a separate service ? I want to have intentservice inside existing service so that i can avoid sending many information to new intent service. pls advise regarding the same.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my answer with an example. You can easiliy replace existing service with IntentService. Another possible solution would be to create an asynchronous Handler in your service and do your heave stuff there. That is exactly what IntentService does, but it is encapsulated.